# Windows 8.1 universal app crashes on Windows 10

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, winrt-xaml, windows-10

My app is already published in the Store, it was built on Windows 8.1 and it perfectly works on 8.1 (desktop and tablet). However it crashes on Windows 10 just after I navigate from page that has a WebView control (though this might not be the reason). I looked at windows logs (eventvwr.msc) and found out the crash has happened in a system library.

Has anybody faced problems with Windows 8.1 apps running on Windows 10?

**UPDATE 1: information from system's event log**
Faulting application name: ....
Faulting module name: twinapi.appcore.dll, version: 10.0.10240.16397, time stamp: 0x55af0938
Exception code: 0xc000027b
Fault offset: : 0x0001cab9
Faulting process id: 0xe30
Faulting application start time: 0x01d0daabb7ab6d89
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps.....
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\twinapi.appcore.dll
Faulting package full name: ....
Faulting package-relative application ID: App

**UPDATE 2**
With help of this article [Debugging a Windows 8.1 Store App Crash Dump](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2014/01/13/debugging-a-windows-8-1-store-app-crash-dump.aspx) I've cracked crash dump and found out the problem method in my code. That method has code that captures a screenshot of a web page with `webView.CapturePreviewToStreamAsync(memoryStream);` and saves it to local file. I suspect webview causes the crash because its core should differ from one on windows 8.1 (is it based on MS Edge instead of IE?).

Comment: I have. My windows 8 app was removed from the store for failing too much after w10 released. It remained on the store since 10-2013 with no issues whatsoever...

Comment: You will have to post more information. No one can tell you what is wrong based on what you have here.

Comment: I've got some information from system's event log, see the UPDATE section in the post.

Comment: I would suggest putting this information in the MSDN forums so MS can have a look at it. You should also use the Feedback app in Windows 10 and select developer at the bottom left.